# WSO2 JSON Array Processing

Tags: wso2

I have a json array (see below) which is logged in my wso2 sequence.

Payload: [{"id":"346","sys":"8","name":"A bldg"},{"id":"345","sys":"8","name":"bbldg 3"}
}]

Now I want to iterate the array. How do I do that? I want to log name for each row for now. I tried few options but it is not working, any help appreciated!.

My sequence looks like this:

```
<sequence name="a3" trace="enable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property expression="json-eval($.payload)" name="array"
        scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <foreach expression="//array/*" sequence="" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>

    <respond/>
</sequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have a JSON input so when it comes inside an ESB the format is changed to xml by default, so as i see that the json input is `[{"id":"346","sys":"8","name":"A bldg"},{"id":"345","sys":"8","name":"bbldg 3"} }]` , ESB will add a root element while converting it into XML.

Now you can use an XSLT to fetch the name or you can use an iterate mediator, which ever suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

Don't take the payload to a property instead directly iterate as below,

```
<foreach expression="//payload">
  <sequence>
    <log>
      <property expression="//name" name="name" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    </log>
  </sequence>
</foreach>
```